# Sharepoint 2010 designer Approval workflow for document

Tags: sharepoint

I am having below requirement using sharepoint 2010 designer workflow.
Once anyone reject the request the workflow must be assigned back to User who is initiating.
Please guide me how can i achive this. I am new to sharepoint workflows. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OOB SharePoint 2010 designer workflow can't achieve this, you would consider to use third-party solution/product for this.

Or develop your state machine workflow.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193520/SharePoint-2010-State-Machine-Workflows-with-Custo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg508985(v%3Doffice.14)